# shared_preference 2.0.6 version

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't dowload shared_preference. please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3IfY.png)

here there is no shared preferenece. I clicked pub get and my internet connection is also good

Comment: Have you tried `flutter clean`? What does your pubspec.yaml file look like?

Comment: @Er1 yes I have. but not working

Comment: Can you add the error message or what shows on the Terminal

Answer (score 2):

I have found answer to my problem
Just I had written $ flutter pub cache repair
to terminal